# Stink to (high heaven/ high hell)

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

"Heaven" makes more sense, but "hell" has a hellscape connotation and is commonly used. Thoughts?

Comment: I've only ever heard 'to high heaven'.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and questions which are a solicitation for opinions, reviews, and other subjective responses are ill-suited to the format. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of what Stack Exchange is and how it operates.

Comment: I've only heard "stinks to high heaven" or "stinks like hell".  I've never heard "to high hell". What do you mean by "commonly used"? ( https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stinks+to+high+heaven%2F%28stinks+to+high+heaven%2Bstinks+to+high+hell%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28stinks%20to%20high%20heaven%20/%20%28stinks%20to%20high%20heaven%20%2B%20stinks%20to%20high%20hell%29%29%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(stinks%20to%20high%20heaven%20%2F%20(stinks%20to%20high%20heaven%20%2B%20stinks%20to%20high%20hell))%3B%2Cc0 )

Answer (score 2):

“High hell” doesn’t really work, for me, because hell is generally considered to be “down” rather than “up” (high).

I’ve never heard the word “hell” used in an expression such as this. “High heaven” is referring more to the distance than anything else, as a way of measuring the degree of something, i.e. it’s a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I've not heard the "hell" version either, but it seems it is sometimes so used (even if "commonly" is a bit dubious, but maybe it is a common expression in some circles or some localities).